# Reversing role of pressing shift+number key in Wayland

Tags: 17.10, keyboard-layout, wayland

Now that Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland by default, I've found by .Xmodmap file not working (duh!). So in Wayland, how do I reverse the role of the number keys? I would prefer the default output to be !@#$%..... and then when applying the Shift key, the output should be 1234.... I have done some preliminary research into this topic but I still haven't found a solution. My basic understanding is that modifying keymaps on Wayland is non-trivial.

This is continuation of the [previous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176671/reversing-role-of-pressing-shiftnumber) question I asked long back for the X11 server.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use the basic *English (US)* layout, you can edit the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file directly (and reboot).

Comment: I modified the _us_ file under name[Group1]= "English (US)"; but that did not work.  Upon reboot, my computer got stuck in a boot loop where the screen just kept periodically flashing.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZVCidYun That's how my modified file looks like which did not work.

Comment: @NahsiN: Missing comma between _asciicircum_ and _6_. Details are important here. ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It works now! Yay. Was freaked out when I couldn't log back in before. Just forgot to double check my modifications. Not as easy as .Xmodmap but for now it works! Thanks again